Why is implicit conversion not allowed in the copy form of initialization when I do not specify explicit?
In C++, I know we cannot use an explicit constructor with the copy form of initialization (with an =) when implicit conversion happens. In other words, we can use the copy form of initialization if explicit is not specified when implicit conversion happens.
So, in the following code snippet:
#include <string>

class A {
public:
    A(const std::string& s = std::string()) :
        ps(new std::string(s)) { }

    A(const A& p) :
        ps(new std::string(*p.ps)), i(p.i) { }
    A& operator=(const A&);
    ~A() { delete ps; }
private:
    std::string* ps;
    int i;
};

A& A::operator=(const A& rhs) {
    auto newp = new std::string(*rhs.ps); 
    delete ps; 
    ps = newp; 
    i = rhs.i;
    return *this; 
}

int main() {
    A v = "abc";
}

My expectation is that "abc" can be implicitly converted to const std::string and thus the first constructor A(const std::string& s) will be called. Since I did not specify explicit for this constructor, I don't see anything that prevents this. But I get an error saying:

cannot convert from 'const char [4]' to 'A'

In the book "C++ Primer", I read "explicit Constructors Can Be Used Only for Direct Initialization" in section 7.5.4 "Implicit Class-Type Conversions". I think my understanding is that such an implicit conversion in the copy initialization form is not allowed only when the constructor is explicit.
But, I did not specify that, and there is only one conversion involved. So, I think A v = "abc"; should have worked. I don't understand why it can't.
===================================================
To the people who closed my question:
I am not asking "How many implicit conversions" are allowed. I clearly know that no more than one implicit conversion are allowed. The crux of my question is what is considered an implicit conversion. For example, why does the compiler not call the string Ctor to construct the variable when we already have a string from one implicit conversion? Why does the compiler make a further implicit conversion to call the copy Ctor? What change we can make to the code snippet to make these rules more clear by, say, adding explicit to one or two Ctors? Please don't hasten to close a question when you have not grasped the main idea and subtlety of the question. This is only harmful to this website.
If the people who closed my question is not convinced. NathanOliver thinks the copy form of initialization (with an =) must use copy Ctor. JaMiT soon comes up with an experiment: A v = std::string{"abc"};. It works, but it does not use copy Ctor even though it uses the copy form of initialization (with an =). Actually it uses the first string Ctor. Why?
Now we may add explicit to the first string Ctor, and an error occurs. The "C++ Primer" text says "One context in which implicit conversions happen is when we use the copy form of initialization (with an =) (§ 3.2.1, p. 84). We cannot use an explicit constructor with this form of initialization;" From this sentence, the error is because we use = AND there is implicit conversions. But there is no implicit conversion in this experiment. So why the error?
Now you may argue that this is because "we must use direct initialization" as the text claims. But if we change the definition of variable v to A v = A(std::string("abc")); there will be no error. This is the copy form of
initialization (with an =), and the string Ctor is still explicit. How to explain?
So, my question can be digged deeper than the so-called duplicated question. It is brusque to close my question and we consequently lost the chance to learn more from my question.
============================================================
Although I appreciate the comments, they are incorrect. The error in my original question has nothing to do with more than one implicit conversion or must call copy Ctor for the copy form of initialization (with an =). The reason is missing suffix of s that is needed to convert string literal to std::string. If writing A v = "abc"s; (together with using namespace std::string_literals;), the literal is converted to std::string and the string Ctor is called to construct v. If the question was not closed, maybe someone could point out this issue, but look at what some powerful politicians of SO have done. Now the question can really be closed.

TL;DR of the dupe: A v = "abc"; requires going from cont char[N] -> std::string -> A.  You are only allowed one of the implicit conversions.

The implicit conversion involved is the first ->. The second -> is the calling of the first Ctor which is not an implicit conversion.

no, the second is still an implicit conversion.  When you use copy initialization the type of the right hand side has to be the same type as the source type.  So "abc" needs to be converted to a std::string and then that string needs to be converted to an A using A's string constructor and then that temporary A is used to construct v using the copy constructor.  That's 2 user defined conversions, std::string counts as a user defined type, and that 1 conversion too many

After we get a std::string using an implicit conversion, why do the compiler not call the string constructor directly to construct v but use a temporary A? Is this because I use the copy init form?

Yes, copy init form means construct from a copy constructor

Short version of what's going on: A v = value; implicitly converts value to A so that it can be copied to v, while A v(value) implicitly converts value to a parameter to a constructor of A (not directly to A). Experiment: Try A v = std::string{"abc"};

Thank you all. I finally understand it. Copy init form sticks to the copy constructor no matter what, even if there is a function match with other Ctor for an intermediate implicit conversion. For this purpose, the compiler will continue to implicitly convert to a temporary A which violates the "Only One Class-Type Conversion" rule. I would appreciate it if you could please write an answer based on the above discussion. Thank you.

"there is only one conversion involved. So, I think A v = "abc"; should have worked. I don't understand why it can't...." No, there are actually two conversions involved. When you wrote A v = "abc;", first the string literal "abc" needs to be converted to a std::string and then std::string needs to be converted to A. The book c++ primer even has an example that is almost identical to yours. You can find that example in the book under the section titled Only One Class-Type Conversion Is Allowed in the 5th edition of the book. I remember this cuz I learnt c++ from this book.

@zzzhhh Let me know if you don't find that section in the book. I'll add more details where it(that section) can be found.

"abc"s is actually a function call and no implicit conversion is involved, so your final paragraph in your edit has little to do with the original question and little to do with how many implicit conversions are allowed.

If you use copy-initialization form and the types on the lhs and rhs are different, it is considered an implicit conversion. That the copy constructor is not actually invoked at runtime is a result of guaranteed copy-elision, which is a orthogonal dimension to the consideration of implicit conversions. I didn't vote to close it, but after reading your long essay I'm still (or even more) convinced that the dup answers your question.
